Macos M2 mysqlclient Symbol not found: _mysql_affected_rows ERROR
I am facing a problem when using Python 3.12 with MySQL client on an M2 chip. The issue is due to the *ARM architecture not being compatible. Is there a solution to this?
Error:

ImportError: dlopen(/Users/user/projects/initial-service/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-312-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '_mysql_affected_rows'

I tried a lot of tricks from the internet, but none of them worked.

Do you have a MySQL client/ mariadb client non-python library installed?

I don't have the MariaDB client installed. I have only installed the MySQL client and Python. Do I need to install the MariaDB client?

more the client libraries - brew install mariadb@10.11 - and export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/homebrew/opt/mariadb@10.11/lib/pkgconfig. Might need a library path set to /opt/homebrew/opt/mariadb@10.11/lib.

Thanks for answering, but nothing was fixed after I installed MariaDB.
